# WebSphere 8,5 spring job with remote ejb xa transaction error

Tags: java, spring, transactions, websphere-8, xa

I'm working with spring batch and WebSphere 8.5. Batch uses a remote ejb in xa distribuited transaction:

```
    org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: UOWManager transaction processing failed; nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: javax.transaction.SystemException
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:297) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:127) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.spr....
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: javax.transaction.SystemException
        at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:823) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: null
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1251) ~[com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1042) ~[com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:963) ~[com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191) ~[com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowCommit(UOWManagerImpl.java:807) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:881) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(UOWManagerImpl.java:782) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:818) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Giancarlo

Comment: Hi, might be worth starting with some tracing - have a look at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21649239

Comment: Thank you, with your help I found the real problem: **RoleBasedAuth E   SECJ0326E: No received or invocation credential exist on the thread. The Role based a
uthorization check will not have an accessId of the caller to check. The parameters are: role name administrator. The stack trace is java.la
ng.Exception: Invocation and received credentials are both null**

Answer (score 0):

after Greycon's help, I resolved disabling security on transaction service.

For WAS 8.5, the procedure is the same as that of WAS 7 described in the following link:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWSR9_11.4.0/com.ibm.mdmhs.bil_install.doc/t_disable_protocol_security.html